# I can't sign in to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014-express

I can't sign in to SQL Server 2014 Express.

I have selected `HP\SQlExpress` as the server name and selected Windows authentication. This login has worked up until yesterday.

When I try to connect I get the error message in the attached screenshot.

[image: Sql]

[image]

Comment: So the server seems to have gone away. Tried rebooting?

Comment: Is `HP` your own computer? If not: has **remote access** been explicitly enabled on that computer's SQL Server Express instance (it's **OFF** by default)

Comment: I restarted Pc and I have the same problem. I looked in services under administrative tools in the control panel and it says that Sql Server(SQL Express) is automatic and the browser is disabled. However under status it is not running

Comment: I presume Hp is my own Pc

Comment: @frustrationmultiplied - you need to ensure that the SQL Server status is running for you enable to connect. marc_s has an answer showing you how to start the service again.

Comment: The `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)` service is there, set to start "automatic" - but it's not running. Either it has trouble starting (you should find some error message in the "Event Viewer") or it's not really, not fully installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to make sure you are logged in as an administrator and then select Control Panel>Administrative Tools>Services>SqlServer>Right Click>Start

Once you have done this you can sign out and log back in with your user account and Sql Server Express 214 will run.

I was logged in by my user account and not my administrator account and that is why the option to restart SqlServer was greyed out in Services when I right Clicked on it.

Many thanks to all who took the time to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the SQL Server agent is running and that the port (Default 1433) is not getting blocked by a firewall.

Also ensure that you are allowing remote connections (If that machine is hosted elsewhere):

[image]

Comment: How do i enure that the port is not getting blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Start Menu > All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2014 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server 2014 Configuration Manager`. You should see something like this:

[image]

Do you see an entry `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)` and is it listed as "State = Running" ? If not, then your SQL Server Express service is just not running....

Comment: Im using windows 10.I dont see an option for configuration tools. When i checked in control panel under admin tools and then selected services it says that the state is blank(not running)

Comment: when i try all programs>Microsft Sql server 2014 there is no option for configuration tools. have you any idea where that might be buried under. would it be in the installation center by any chance. i cant find it

Comment: the only thing i can find is an sql reporting services configuration manager

Comment: Hit the Windows key. Type "services". Choose Services (Desktop app). Look for SQL Server (sqlexpress). Is it running? If not, right click and choose "Start". If it doesn't start, there's something more serious going on with it, and you'll need to look through the events in your Windows Event Log to figure out what's broken. (SQL Server errors will typically, I think, be in the Windows/Application Events section of the Event Viewer)

Comment: Ive right clicked on it but the start option is greyed out. the only sql services that are running are the reporting services and vss writer.

Comment: ive added a screenshot to my original question showing the services available atm

Comment: ive done a search for windows/applcation event viewer and when it comes up there is notthing relating to sql server

Comment: ive tried >services>sql server agent>right clicking>properties trying to change startup type manually but that is greyed out and doesnt allow me type anything in. Can you help out

Comment: Are you logged in as an admin user? Maybe you need to start the services app by right clicking on it and choosing "Run as administrator". (I don't, but it's probably worth trying if you don't seem to have permission to start a service.) Are you logged in as the user who installed SQL Server in the first place?